# Undefined method '_helper_methods' for Controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here's the [Sentry](https://sentry.io/share/issue/3131333534392e313834373331303430) link.

The problem is that sometimes (several times a day) I get this error message while trying to add a helper to the controller:

```
helper_name = "#{helper}_path".to_sym
self.class.send(:define_method, helper_name) { |*args| send "#{helper}_#{MySettings.route_code}_path", *args }
self.class.helper_method helper_name
```

This code iterates over an array of URL helper names (like `%w(stocks bonds currencies)`). Then it creates a symbol `helper_name` and defines a method in the Controller (the whole code is in `before_action`). The generated method is accessing URL helper for specific domain. The third line just makes the generated method available in the views by calling `helper_method` on the controller.

I also have constraints in my routes like this:

```
constraints host: lambda { |h| h == Settings.de_domain || h == "www.#{Settings.de_domain}" \
                              || h == Settings.at_domain || h == "www.#{Settings.at_domain}" \
                              || h == Settings.ch_domain || h == "www.#{Settings.ch_domain}" } do
```

The website is frequently visited. Also it's connected to several domains (`nl`, `de`, `be` etc). The error can happen on any domain.
Any idea of why this can happen and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Can you give a description of what that code is a actually supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @max Sure, I've added the description.

Comment: Why not just declare the routes with resources and with a domain constraint?

Comment: I already have constrains. Please see updates. But that's a legacy code. I don't have opportunity to refactor all routes now. I have just to fix the error.